# How to send the data stored in python variables to oracle database table using cx_oracle?

Tags: python, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I have extracted some contact information from a website using an `api` and print it using python but I need it to send the data to my oracle database where I have already created a table. It will be really helpful if you can do it using `cx_oracle`.

I want the output in the database table.

```
    import requests
    url = "https://********.api-us1.com/api/3/contacts? 
    include=fieldValues&limit=100&orders[cdate]=DESC"
    httpHeader={'Api-Token''3d229bde5b7f8e03ada8d0ef5ac0be70bdf1693f3c781caf9255237*******c03a438da'}
    response = requests.get(url,headers=httpHeader).json()
    number_of_contacts_str        = response['meta']['total']
    number_of_contacts            = int(number_of_contacts_str)
    i=0
    print()
    print('{:^10}{:^20}{:^20}{:^14}{:^30}{:^20}{:^20}'.format('Sl.No','First Name','Last Name','Phone','Email','Course','Date'))
    print()
    while i<number_of_contacts:
        date            = response['contacts'][i]['cdate']
        email           = response['contacts'][i]['email']
        phone           = response['contacts'][i]['phone']
        firstName       = response['contacts'][i]['firstName']
        lastName        = response['contacts'][i]['lastName']
        course          = response['fieldValues'][i]['value']
        date_response1  = response['fieldValues'][i]['cdate']
        print('{:^10}{:<20}{:<20}{:<14}{:<30}{:<20}{:<20}'.format((i+1),firstName,lastName,phone,email,course,date))
        #print(response)
        #print(date)
        i+=1
```

The output is

```
    Sl.No        First Name          Last Name          Phone                 Email                    Course               Date        

1     NameTwentyThree     Wayne               7867904678    nametwentythree@gmail.com     Twenty three        2018-12-08T14:51:39-06:00
2     NameTwentyTwo       Arigato             6578967543    nametwentytwo@gmail.com       Twenty two          2018-12-08T14:50:09-06:00
3     NameTwentyOne       Parker              7856748397    nametwentyone@gmail.com       Twenty one          2018-12-08T14:48:56-06:00
4     NameTwenty          Konichiwa           6748397289    nametwenty@gmail.com          Twenty              2018-12-08T14:46:46-06:00
5     NameNinteen         Lee                 9867456738    nameninteen@gmail.com         Ninteen             2018-12-08T14:45:50-06:00
6     NameEighteen        Shroff              8695047837    nameeighteen@gmail.com        Eighteen            2018-12-08T14:44:41-06:00
7     NameSeventeen       Kapoor              8746983767    nameseventeen@gmail.com       Seventeen           2018-12-08T14:43:46-06:00
8     NameSixteen         Deb                 7859478938    namesixteen@gmail.com         Sixteen             2018-12-08T14:42:49-06:00
9     NameFifteen         Chan                8758905789    namefifteen@gmail.com         Fifteen             2018-12-08T14:41:53-06:00
10    NameFourteen        Kimmel              7865749046    namefourteen@gmail.com        Fourteen            2018-12-08T14:40:51-06:00
11    NameThirteen        Jackson             6789564567    namethirteen@gmail.com        Thirteen            2018-12-08T14:37:59-06:00
12    NameTwelve          Roy                 5643789567    nameatwelve@gmail.com         Twelve              2018-12-08T14:04:51-06:00
13    NameEleven          Sarkar              7678956745    nameeleven@gmail.com          Eleven              2018-12-08T14:03:59-06:00
14    NameTen             Maheshwari          8796568987    nameten@gmail.com             Ten                 2018-12-08T14:02:05-06:00
15    NameNine            Mehta               7657875357    namenine@gmail.com            Nine                2018-12-08T14:01:19-06:00
16    NameEight           Ahmed               6758947383    nameeight@gmail.com           Eight               2018-12-08T14:00:29-06:00
17    NameSeven           Gogoi               6759483789    nameseven@gmail.com           Seven               2018-12-08T13:59:38-06:00
18    NmaeSix             Pait                6759738399    namesix@gmail.com             Six                 2018-12-08T13:58:56-06:00
19    NameFive            Roshan              6784637909    namefive@gmail.com            Five                2018-12-08T13:58:14-06:00
20    NameTwo             Sharma              8578936765    nametwo@gmail.com             Two                 2018-12-08T13:55:55-06:00
21    NameOne             Singh               7859473939    nameone@gmail.com             One                 2018-12-08T13:55:05-06:00
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please tell us what error do you get when you run this code.

Comment: sorry i have edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: I still don't see any error. Are you sure that your table is not updated in database ? + you removed from your post the part that actually inserts into database ..

Comment: The part which i have removed had the code to connect to the database and send data which is manually inserted. I want my code to send the output from the above program (which will change from time to time). Specifically, the values stored in 'date','firstname', 'lastname','email','course' and 'phone'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already succeeded to connect to the database, then all you need to do is build up a list of tuples that looks something like the following:

```
data = [
    ('NameTwentyThree', 'Wayne', '7867904678', 'nametwentythree@gmail.com'),
    ('NameTwentyTwo', 'Arigato', '6578967543', 'nametwentytwo@gmail.com'),
]

cursor.executemany("""
    insert into TheTable (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Email)
    values (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)""", data)
```

You can build up the data by appending to the list using the results you got from your other API. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Can you share me a source where I can learn this properly. I didn't understand "values (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)" part. I simply put :1,:1,:1,:1 and it worked.

Comment: You're very welcome. You can take a look at the sample (https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BindInsert.py) and the documentation (https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.executemany). The reason that :1, :1, :1, :1, :1 works is because you are using positional binds and each bind is managed by its position. The use of other numbers if for the human being that is reading the code!